# How to use NOR gate in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Hi do we have any logic to use NOR gate in javascript 
I need a logic

!(a || b)
(!a && !b)
 these both are not working

I tried and I couldn't get

where
     i/p     i/p   o/p as
      T    .   T  =   F
      T   .    F   =  F
      F   .    T   =  F
      F   .    F   =  T

Comment: NOR is simply `!(a || b)`.

Comment: what if you have more than 2 values to be used for NOT gate @Pointy

Comment: Why would that be any different? The logic operation is the same.

Comment: @Neabfi that wont work

Comment: @KowsikGunasekaran ... That's what NOR is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate

Comment: @KowsikGunasekaran - please don't change the question in the comments. Please edit your question if you want to modify what you are asking (aka what if...)

Comment: If you have 4 inputs: `!(a || b || c || d)`

Comment: @KowsikGunasekaran ... That's still a NOR.

Answer (score 2):

You do simply do `!(a || b)`.

If you have 4 inputs: `!(a || b || c || d)`.

Comment: what if input has more than two values

Comment: @KowsikGunasekaran Add the additional values. Or accumulate then negate. It's not clear to me what the issue is.